# My Application was deployed successfully but showing 500 server error

Tags: google-app-engine, server-error

Google App Engine

```
2013-11-13 00:45:52 Running command: "['C:\\Python27\\pythonw.exe', '-u', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\appcfg.py', '--no_cookies', u'--email=sulemannbd@gmail.com', '--passin', 'update', 'C:\\google\\test']"
12:45 AM Application: testcboy; version: 1
12:45 AM Host: appengine.google.com
12:45 AM 
Starting update of app: testcboy, version: 1
12:45 AM Getting current resource limits.
Password for sulemannbd@gmail.com: 12:46 AM Scanning files on local disk.
12:46 AM Cloning 167 application files.
12:46 AM Uploading 7 files and blobs.
12:46 AM Uploaded 7 files and blobs
12:46 AM Compilation starting.
12:46 AM Compilation completed.
12:46 AM Starting deployment.
12:46 AM Checking if deployment succeeded.
12:46 AM Deployment successful.
12:46 AM Checking if updated app version is serving.
12:46 AM Completed update of app: testcboy, version: 1
2013-11-13 00:46:18 (Process exited with code 0)

You can close this window now.
```

This log generated, when i deployed app on Google. But it is showing the

> Error: Server Error The server encountered an error and could not
>   complete your request.
>
> If the problem persists, please report your problem and mention this
>   error message and the query that caused it.

Can I anyone tell me , why i am seeing this error?? 
**APP was working fine few hours back.** 
You can check the app at  http://testcboy.appspot.com/

Error Log

```
XX.XXX.XXX.XX - - [12/Nov/2013:11:32:49 -0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 0 - "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36" "testcboy.appspot.com" ms=61 cpu_ms=0 loading_request=1 exit_code=204 app_engine_release=1.8.7 instance=00c61b117ca04018be59d2d5878f8fb3467f71
I 2013-11-12 11:32:49.816
This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application.
W 2013-11-12 11:32:49.816
A problem was encountered with the process that handled this request, causing it to exit. This is likely to cause a new process to be used for the next request to your application. (Error code 204)
```

Comment: look in the logs in the app engine console, filter to "error" and see the cause that way. Also if you have debug=True you should get more then a 500 error.

Comment: @PaulCollingwood I had added the error logs in the question, can you please tell me how to resolve these errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because of app.yaml file. 
I was using as given belowin my locahost on GAE and it was working fine , but it dont work when deployed on server.

```
- url: /(.*)\.php
  script: /\1.php
```

for deploying it on server you need to do it like this.

- url: /(.*).php
  script: \1.php

second implementation dont start with slash(i.e in 2nd line script: **-no-slash-here**\1.php)

Answer (score 0):

The app is working now. Google App Engine often shows error 500s while initially starting up because it is so slow to start up and it kills itself when it fails to meet its own deadline for responding to a request.

Comment: Thankyou, I also want to know, that can i use external database for application hosted on Google Aap Engine... 
I have a database hosted on GoDaddy.in

Comment: I have no idea - please ask a new question.