# Server Error (500) "The server encountered an error and could not complete your request" on App Engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, zend-framework

I am trying to deploy my site based on Zend Framework1 to App Engine Google.
It works after deploy, but sometimes I have an error and I don't know on what it depend.
This error is appearing at any time (once every 2-3 minutes) on any page:
[image: Screen from page when error:]

Logs from google developers console:

> A problem was encountered with the process that handled this request, causing it to exit. This is likely to cause a new process to be used for the next request to your application. (Error code 204)

My app.yaml:

```
application: app-name
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /img
  static_dir: public/img

- url: /js
  static_dir: public/js

- url: /css
  static_dir: public/css

- url: /.*
  script: public/mod-rewrite.php
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be because zend framework uses cURL internally, which is not supported on appengine. If you would like to write a zend-appengine patch that replaces the cURL calls with url-fetch, you would be a hero of all time.

Although, sometimes this same error comes from calling log.fatal or os.exit, or [also from a misconfigured app.yaml](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19939689/4270992).

Hope this helps you track down the error.

Comment: cURL is being release in 1.9.17 - see https://gae-php-tips.appspot.com/2014/11/15/app-engine-php-1-9-17-pre-release-sdk/

Comment: I checked, it is not cURL problem. I get this error even on the page, where I don't use cURL.

Comment: Most probably related to https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9786